# How to traverse Tridion xml data using Tridion Object Model?

Tags: tom.net

I'm new to Tridion, I would like to use the Tridion Object Model API to get and traverse the Tridion XML data with an XSLT template? How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange, Please provide bit more details of which version of Tridion and about your implementation? why XSLT template? why not Dreamviewer template or C# template or Razor template? the reason why I'm asking because the SDL Tridion sites 9.0+ version no more VB Script and XSLT templates are supported.

Comment: @Velmurugan Good questions. Still - XSLT is just as supported as Razor... what Tridion supports is mediators, and there's also an XSLT mediator available. The old kind of XSLT templating is indeed long gone, though.

Comment: @DominicCronin: AFAIK - We can still use IFunctionSource functions in a DLL that is stored in the GAC to use for DW and Razor templating, not sure, I have not tested with latest versions of sites 9.0+.